# rsync not appending to its log file

Tags: rsync

I'm using `rsync --log-file=...` on my QNAP NAS and it is not appending to the log file when running via cron.  Running the same command from the command line does append.

This command appends from the command line:

```
rsync -rvs -e ssh --log-file=/share/homes/admin/rsync.log --ignore-existing "/source/" "/destination/"
```

cron entry:

```
30 * * * * /share/homes/admin/bin/myscript.sh
```

The script `myscript.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

LOCKFILE=/var/log/$(basename "$0").lock
LOGFILE=/share/homes/admin/rsync.log
if [ -e /var/log/$LOCKFILE ]
then
        echo "Rsync job already running...exiting" >> "$LOGFILE"
        exit
else
        touch "$LOCKFILE"
fi

trap 'rm "$LOCKFILE"' EXIT

rsync -rvs -e ssh --log-file="$LOGFILE" --ignore-existing "/source/" "/destination/"
if [ "$?" -gt "0" ]
then
  /share/homes/admin/bin/email.sh
fi
```

Running just the `rsync` command in the script still does not append to the `rsync` log file.

Sometimes, very rarely it *does* append for a while and then stops and overwrites.  That's weird too.

I could redirect the output of the `rsync` command but I then will lose all the timestamps that `rsync` adds, so I would rather find the cause if I could.

Comment: Are you by any chance transferring the log file itself in the transfer with `rsync`?

Comment: No I am not transferring the log file.